# iOS - Simple SSL socket connection

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, ssl

What is the correct way to create a SSL socket connection in iOS?

I've implemented a SSL server in Java by:

- creating a SSL certificate with a store password
- loading it by setting the system properties "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" and "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"
- creating a SSLServerSocket with the SSLServerSocket factory

Now I want to create a client app which opens a socket connection in a thread and communicates over that. What is the proper way to create such a connection and do the communication with my servers certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` to connect using TLS as per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237735/nsstream-ssl-on-used-socket).

**EDIT**:
Rather than use the SSL settings in that answer, I would suggest this:

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{ 
    (__bridge NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel:(__bridge NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL 
};
```

This uses the following defaults:

```
kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates:  NO
kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot: NO
kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: YES
```

If you want to set the security level to use a particular version of SSL or TLS, take a look at the values in `CFSocketStream.h`.

Comment: Thanks, but is it safe to use _kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot_?

Comment: Safe, yes because it's a valid option. Is it secure? No.

Comment: So then.. what would be the right way to create a _secure_ connection? ;)

Comment: Okay, so far so good, but as my streams do not allow "any root" anymore, how do I make my servers SSL certificate to be allowed?

Comment: If you need to allow any root, then apply that setting. If you want to use a custom root certificate, ensure it's in the keychain on your device.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create a certificate if you are making a client app not a server one.
To do it in iOS, there are a number of ways, the simplest is to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library.
Just put the url (https) inside one of its methods, and you are ready.
I used it many times. Just spend 5 mins to read the doc.

Comment: `SSLServerSocket` is, as one would imagine, a socket server and not a web server.

Comment: @guiseppe I don't want to create just a client that opens some kind of HTTPS connection. I want to create a SSL socket connection to my own Java server where I cant send plain bytes...